# Wordpress Plugin about count posts

Tags: php, widget, wordpress

I am trying to count author's post count in a month. So, I don't know how to code and save anywhere. I think it must be interface. Any offers?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts